# How to combine ReactJs, Auth0 and Cordova?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, auth0

I've built a web app using ReactJs, with auth0 for authentication. Now, when I use Cordova to wrap it up and create a native application, I face an issue due to the redirection done by Auth0 for authentication.

I've tried creating a native app in auth0 and using the "react-cordova" package to properly build and wrap the react app into a Cordova app, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning! My name is Jim Morrison and I'm a part of the Auth0 Community team. Are you seeing any breakdown in your auth0 logs? We have a this Community maintained Cordova quickstart that you could check against your current implementation to see if everything looks to be in it's place. I hope this helps but if it doesn't be sure to let us know!

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/cordova/01-login

Comment: Hello Jim

Thanks for responding. I've tried using this quickstart, but don't understand how I could combine it with an already built react js application. In that application, I was using your auth0-spa-js package.